# Get Document Views from Client Side

Tags: client-object-model, web-services, csom, auditing

We have a SharePoint 2013 intranet site that contains a Document List. There are .xlsx documents and .rdl documents. I want to know which users viewed which documents. I want to get this information programmatically, and with client tools.

For the .rdl documents, I can query the ReportServer database and the ExecutionLog3 view. In the past, for the .xlsx views, we have queried the auditdata table in the SharePoint content database. However, our SharePoint admin is not comfortable with doing this. **So, I need a way to get this information using the Client Side Object Model, or using the "_vti_bin/Lists.asmx" web service (or if there is another way).**

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I am doubting is Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Site.Audit class allows getting audit reports, but can you not use the SPAudit class with server side code to get the reports?

Comment: Hi @Nisarg, that might be an option, but I would need the SP Admin to set something up. I would prefer a solution that I can manage on the client side. If there isn't a good client solution, then I would have to have the SP admin set something up.